# Mathematica gives a solution to a differential equation that does not verify it

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

The equation I want to solve numerically with WolframCloud is:

```
z[t_] := Exp[2*Sqrt[L/3]*t]
Eq1 = -40/9*L-20/3*y''[t]/y[t]+2/3*y'[t]^2/y[t]^2-6*z'[t]*y'[t]/(z[t]*y[t])+11/6*z'[t]^2/z[t]^2-360/7*1/y[t]^2+97/21*1/(y[t]^2*z[t])==0
```

I want to solve it for y[t] only, and then verify that it gives y[t] such that if I want to solve this equation for z[t], it returns the correct exponential function. To do so, I use the following code:

```
Clear[F,R,y]
L = 0.038;
sol0 = NDSolve[{Eq1, y[0]==0.1, y'[0]==5.5},y[t],{t, 0, 1}];
R[t_]:=Evaluate[y[t]/.sol0]
Eq2 =-40/9*L-20/3*R''[t]/R[t]+2/3*R'[t]^2/R[t]^2-6*F'[t]*R'[t]/(F[t]*R[t])+11/6*F'[t]^2/F[t]^2-360/7*1/R[t]^2+97/21*1/(R[t]^2*F[t])==0;
sol = NDSolve[{Eq2,F[0]==1},F[t],{t,0,10},MaxSteps->10000][[1]];
Plot[{Log[Evaluate[F[t]/.sol]], 2*Sqrt[L/3]*t},{t,0,1}]
```

As you see, I plot only the log of the function so it should give two superimposed lines. But it gives me this:
[image]

We can see that until $\sim 0.6$ it gives the correct behavior, but I can't explain what is going on with my code to give a wrong answer... Have I done something wrong in my code?

EDIT: After having played with the parameters, it seems that the point where F[t] deviates from the line $2 \sqrt{\frac{L}{3}} t$ is exactly the middle of the domain of definition of R[t]. In fact, R[t] has roughly the shape of $-at^2+b$, and so its domain of definition has a maximum right at its half. I don't know what it means but if anyone has an idea...

Comment: Well, one obvious issue  is that you solve first ode for up to $t=1$. Then you used the solution in the second ode which you now solved for up to $t=10$. So it will extrapolate the first solution, which is not good. Try to solve first ode for $t=10$. But it is stiff ode. So you can try reducing `AccuracyGoal` and add `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"},` to help., Your second ode is also stiff. May be more special options are needed. I get in V 13.0.1 `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 1.3637473398450544, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your comment! I've tried to change to $t=10$ in the first equation and to add the Method, but it gives the same plot at the end...

Comment: You can simplify your code a little by writing `R = NDSolveValue[{Eq1, y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 5.5}, y, {t, 0, 1}]` and now you do not need to do `R[t_]:=Evaluate[y[t]/.sol0]`

Comment: @Nasser I tried to do so, but it gives me errors...

Comment: @Nasser I cannot open the notebook because I didn't subscribe to a plan in WolframCloud, but did you get the right straight lines in the plot?

Comment: `NDSolve` fails at `t == 1.3642051492474077`, because `y` vanishes there.

Comment: I recommend that `Evaluate[y[t]/.sol0]` be replaced by `Evaluate[y[t]/.Flatten[sol0]]`, but that will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sol0 = NDSolve[{Eq1, y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 5.5}, y[t], {t, 0, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> All];
```

solves the problem. With the rest of the code as in the question, the final plot is

[image]

The difficulty with the original code is that `R[t]` is a third order interpolation function.  Hence, `R''[t]` is only first order, which apparently is not accurate enough to recover `z[t]`. The option `InterpolationOrder -> All` leads to more accurate interpolation of higher derivatives.